# Is double-stranded DNA denatured to single-stranded DNA in retorted canned tuna?

Tags: dna, dna-sequencing, food, dna-damage

A PCR reaction has a cycle of about 55°C annealing, 72°C extension and 95°C denaturing with short time spans. Retorting canned tuna heats the tuna to 115°C to 121°C for 30 minutes to 2 hours depending on steam temperature and can size. So, much of the DNA is degraded into short segments of less than 150 to 200 bp long.

Has the DNA at that temperature been degraded to single-stranded DNA as well, or is is just short segments of double-stranded DNA?

---

Citations for heating causing shorter DNA fragments in processed meats:

- Ebbehøj, K. F., and P. D. Thomsen. 1991. [Species differentiation of heated meat products by DNA hybridization](https://doi.org/10.1016/0309-1740(91)90068-2). Meat Science, 30(3), 221-234.
- Şakalar, E., M. F. Abasiyanik, E. Bektik, and A. Tayyrov. 2012. [Effect of heat processing on DNA quantification of meat species](https://doi.org/10.1111/j.1750-3841.2012.02853.x). J Food Sci. 77(9): N40-N44.

Retorting fragments mtDNA in any meat product. More than 3 dozen papers on retorted tuna DNA alone.

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. Your second paragraph sounds like a conclusion, but isn't obviously based on the preceding paragraph. Are you claiming that 'retorting' fragments the DNA? If so, can you provide a citation or other reference that supports that? ——— It would also be helpful if you could say why you want to know this seemingly random factoid. ——— Please take the [tour] and consult the [help] starting with [ask] for details about site usage and expectations.

Comment: 38. Ebbehøj, K. F., and P. D. Thomsen. 1991. Species differentiation of heated meat products by DNA hybridization. Meat Science, 30(3), 221-234.  https://doi.org/10.1016/0309-1740(91)90068-2

Comment: 89. Şakalar, E., M. F. Abasiyanik, E. Bektik, and A. Tayyrov. 2012. Effect of heat processing on DNA quantification of meat species. J Food Sci. 77(9): N40-N44.  https://doi.org/10.1111/j.1750-841.2012.02853.x

Comment: Retorting fragments mtDNA.  in any meat product.  More than 3 dozen papers on retorted tuna DNA alone.

Comment: Great, please [edit] those into your post — comments on this site are ephemeral and often overlooked, so they should only be used to discuss the post not to amend it. ——— You may be best placed to answer this question. In a typical molecular biology context I would hazard an answer, but I'm not sure how relevant what I do know will be for a complex, non-aqueous material like tuna. In solution, DNA that has 'melted' (strands are separated) will reanneal, but the rate of that reannealing depends on the complexity of the sequence — see: [Cot curves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cot_analysis).

Comment: Thank you sir.  the Cot curves site is very helpful.  My question has not practical significance for us, except it is very helpful to exactly how things are working, in the PCR reaction.  Again, thanks very much for your help.

Comment: What does the word “retorted” mean in this context? The only definition I can deduce is from the chemical apparatus, retort. Please clarify by editing your question.

Comment: It is ssDNA. At retort temperatures (110C - 135C) the hydrogen bonds are broken and the DNA is single stranded. From what you wrote the size of the DNA fragments also changes based on temperature. If however you let the DNA sit for some time and cool after exposure to these temperatures some fragment can reanneal.